# Getting started with GIT, basic flow

Tags: command-line, git

I'm getting started with GIT and would like to know a very simple workflow for branching.

I'm hosting my repo online and have various features to add locally.
It's our plan to make feature branches for each feature and merge them as and when they reach maturity.

I'm literally just getting started with |GIT and I would like to know if I've missed anything important, got it entirely wrong or have a workable solution before I learn bad habits.

I only need to do 2 things currently:

1. Create a new branch for each feature
2. Edit and existing branch

### Make a new branch for feature_x

```
git checkout -b feature_x
//make changes to files
git add .
git commit -m "my notes" -a
git push origin feature_x
```

Seems to be working.

### Edit branch for feature_x

```
git fetch --all
git checkout feature_x
//make changes to files
git add .
git commit -m "my notes" -a
git push origin feature_x
```

Seems to be working.

Have I missed anything important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of useful features you also have is rebase. You keep branches before they are matured. Then, the master branch is keep evolving and branches should be keep updated. Let say, for example, you merge branch1 into master and then you checkout (existing) branch2; you would want branch2 also contain the latest version of the master which contains branch1. It is what `git rebase` does. Thus, working flow will be something like this:

```
git checkout feature_x
//update base code
git rebase master
//make changes to files
git add .
//...
```